# Custom cursor adapter, custom view and cursor loader

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-loader

Is it possible to to use a cursor loader with a custom view (NOT A LIST VIEW)?

Here is an example of a custom cursor adapter with a list view:

```
mMyCursorAdapter = new MyAdapterCursor(getActivity(), null, 0);
setListAdapter(mMyCursorAdapter);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Instead of a list view I want to populate a custom view. The cursor will bring back one record which will populate the view.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an adapter to do that, just get the data out of the Cursor directly and populate the view with it.

For example:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.my_text_view );
tv.setText( myCursor.getString( myCursor.getColumnIndex( "string_column" ) ) );
```

Ideally you'd do this in onLoadFinished, where it will happen once your CursorLoader is done loading the data.

Comment: ahh ok - I'm with you. Being a little slow today.

Comment: Ralgha is right, but I feel his example is a little misleading. Simply modify `onLoadFinished()` to do whatever your want when the CursorLoader is ready. (I don't recommend doing this in `onCreate()`.)

Comment: I actually only need the concept not the example - or is it my example that's vague?!

Comment: @Haraldo Sorry, I feel Ralpha's example is misleading.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't use the new Loader method, I'll edit my answer.